# How to add ng-click or ng-dblclick conditionally in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, html, dom

I have below sample html markup

`<div ng-style="{'height' : myHeight +'px'}" ng-dblclick="myCtrl.clickme()"></div>`

How I can add conditionally in DOM ng-click or ng-dblclick attributes in markup??

Comment: Can you please explain in details?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it in the same markup, however you can have two markups and apply condition as,

```
   <div ng-style="{'height' : myHeight +'px'}" ng-if="contitionforDblClick()" ng-dblclick="myCtrl.clickme()"></div>
   <div ng-style="{'height' : myHeight +'px'}" ng-if="contitionforClick()" ng-click="myCtrl.clickme()"></div>
```